# Is there a standard interface to switch between using Redis and Rabbit in .NET?

Tags: c#, redis, rabbitmq

I wonder if there is a .NET interface that makes the transition between Redis and Rabbit, without (big) changes in the code?

In case I eventually want to change Rabbit to Redis, because during my tests I needed more performance, for example.

I want to do this without much effort with an interface.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just isolate the required functionality behind app-specific custom interface and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's classic inversion of control example, where you want defer implementation details.

This, as suggested in comment, is achieved by app specific interface. So for your code to be closed to modifications, it is required for it to be placed in separate project, where you'd also define interfaces, such as

```
public interface IService
{
    Task DoSomethingAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

and then create separate project for Rabbit and one for Redis (each project would then have further, specialized nugets to handle specific communication).

Now the trick is in each project implement interface `IService` and method implementation will use underlaying provider.

This way once you need Rabbit, you have separate project for it and you just implement the interface again, but using Rabbit provider.

And you defer the decision on what implementation to use to calling code, which is composition root, where you define services. It will most probably look like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IService, RabbitService>();
```

and you use instances of `IService` everywhere.

Once you need to switch, you will just change above line to:

```
services.AddScoped<IService, RedisService>();
```

... so here you have the way to have this changes with close to no code changes.

If your dependcy injection configuration lies within some external config (which is not widely applied) you don't have to touch even the code.